# tensorflow conv2d number of parameters

Tags: conv-neural-network

Want to know why number of parameters in conv2d is more by 1 than what I expect...

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
input_shape = (40, 512, 512, 1)
conv2d = keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape=input_shape[1:],
                         filters=1,
                         kernel_size=3,
                         strides=(1, 1),
                         padding='same')

model = keras.Sequential(conv2d)
model.compile()
model.summary()

Output:

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 512, 512, 1)       10        
=================================================================
Total params: 10
Trainable params: 10
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As kernel size is 3, I was expecting it to be Param # as 9 but its 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `use_bias=True`. There's a bias for each filter, so in this case you add 1 more parameter for the bias. This gives a total of 10 parameters.